# Raspberry pi & OpenCV of C language libarary

Tags: c, opencv

i am working on Project using Raspberry pi and pi camera board.

and i want to install opencv based on C language.

What is the command about installing OpenCV based on C language on Raspberry pi Board ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`
And go check this [page](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/).